# android XML parse into Hash map not working

Tags: android, xml, arraylist, xml-parsing, hashmap

I am getting the most bizzarre behavior with trying to parse an `XML`, I run through it step by step and all values are assigned and retrieved in order and then the object I create is added to a `HashMap` for easy look up, the problem is when I am done retrieving it all the `HashMap` has null values and the ones that aren't null are the value of the very last node that was read, I have walked through it over and over and it all seems correct, but when it's done loading the values in the `HasMap` look like:

```
[0] null
[1] NarrationItem@44e9d170
[2] null
[3] null
[4] NarrationItem@44e9d170
```

etc, etc.

The format of my XML files is:

```
<narrations>
    <narration id="0" name="A" alias="a" >
        <line text="This is a test."></line>
    </narration>
    <narration id="1" name="B" alias="b" >
        <line text="This another a test."></line>
    </narration>
    <narration id="2" name="C" alias="c" >
        <line text="This is STILL a test."></line>
    </narration>
</narrations>
```

And my `XML` parsing method is follows:

```
 public HashMap<String, NarrationItem> NarrationMap = new HashMap<String, NarrationItem>();

 private void LoadNarrationsXML() {
     NarrationItem i = new NarrationItem();
     String line;
     String s;

     try {
         // Get the Android-specific compiled XML parser.
         XmlResourceParser xmlParser = this.getResources().getXml(R.xml.narrations);
         while (xmlParser.getEventType() != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
             if (xmlParser.getEventType() == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG) {
                  s = xmlParser.getName();
                  if (s.equals("narration")) {
                      i.Clear();
                      i.ID  = xmlParser.getAttributeIntValue(null, "id", 0);
                      i.Name = xmlParser.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
                      i.Alias = xmlParser.getAttributeValue(null, "alias");
                  } else if (s.equals("line")) { 
                      line = xmlParser.getAttributeValue(null, "text");
                      i.Narration.add(line);
                  }
            } else if (xmlParser.getEventType() == XmlResourceParser.END_TAG) {
                  s = xmlParser.getName();
                  if (s.equals("narration")) {
                       NarrationMap.put(i.Alias, i);
                  }

             } 
             xmlParser.next();
         }
         xmlParser.close();
     } catch (XmlPullParserException xppe) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Failure of .getEventType or .next, probably bad file format");
          xppe.toString();
     } catch (IOException ioe) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Unable to read resource file");
          ioe.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

The NarrationItem object is a custom object defined as:

```
public class NarrationItem {

int ID;
String Name;
String Alias;
ArrayList<String> Narration = new ArrayList<String>(); 


public NarrationItem() { }

public void LoadNarration(int id, String name, String alias, ArrayList<String> narration) {

    ID = id;
    Name = name;
    Alias = alias;
    Narration.addAll(narration);// = narration;
}


public void Clear() {
    ID = 0;
    Name = "";
    Alias = "";
    Narration.clear();
}

  }//End Narration
```

If someone could point out the problem I'd be very thankful I have sat here staring at this issue for hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only ever creating one `NarrationItem` object - you're then using a reference to that object as the value for multiple entries in the map. Don't do that. You need to understand that the map doesn't contain an *object* as the value - it contains a *reference* to an object.

You can probably fix this just by creating a new `NarrationItem` each time instead of calling `Clear`.

It's not clear how you're looking at the map to see those null values, but if you're using the debugger and looking at the internal data structure, you probably shouldn't really be doing that either - instead, step through the keys, values or entries, i.e. stick within the abstraction that `HashMap` is meant to support.

Comment: I didn't realize it was referencing the object, I made it call New NarrationItem each time and the "not null" items are now correct, Yes I was looking at the debugger to see the values in the Hashmap table

It's still not quite working right, but it's atleast populating the hasmap with correct key/value pairs - thanks!

Comment: Everything appears to be working, their is no explanation for the null values in the Hashmap, but since a hashmap looks up values by key and not an index it doesn't matter - I suspect that what I am seeing isn't the true structure of the Hashmap just a way Eclipse can visualize it

Comment: @GideonKain: The null values in the hash map are just bits which haven't been populated - it's entirely expected that the underlying array will be relatively sparsely populated. The hash lookup uses the hash code of the key to work out which bucket to look in.

Comment: @Jon completely unrelated (adding this here just because this happens to be your latest activity right now), I thought you might be intersted in contributing to [this  question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614361/standards-for-date-time-addition), as there doesn't seem to be an obvious good answer. If not, just ignore me.

Comment: @Pekka: Interesting question - wish I knew of a standards-based answer!

Comment: @Jon yeah, and on the few standards that exist, documentation seems to be very, very scarce. That is an interesting question to watch - I think I'll  put a bounty on it in a couple days.