# Standards for Date/Time addition?

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, datetime, standards

I'm looking for standards for Date/Time addition. I haven't been able to find any. In particular I'm hoping to find a spec that defines what should happen when you add a month to a date like January 31st. Is the right answer February 28th(/29th)? March 1st? March 2nd?

I've seen inconsistent implementations between different tools (PHP & MySQL in this case), and I'm trying to find some sort of standards to base my work on.

Differing Results:

**PHP**

```
$end = strtotime("+1 month", 1314835200);
//1317513600   Sat, 01 Oct 2011 20:00:00 -0400
```

**MySQL**

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(1314835200), INTERVAL 1 MONTH));
#1317427200    Fri, 30 Sep 2011 20:00:00 -0400
```

**Oracle**

```
SELECT ADD_MONTHS('31-Aug-11', 1) FROM dual;
#30-SEP-11
```

(sorry for the format change, my oracle foo is weak)

**Java**

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.clear();
c.set( 2011, Calendar.AUGUST, 31 );
c.add( Calendar.MONTH, 1 );
c.getTime()
#Fri Sep 30 00:00:00 EDT 2011
```

Comment: There are basically two types of hells: Encoding hell and Datetime hell.

Comment: I think one quasi-standard is somewhere in whichever ancient (Unix?) library defines `strtotime()`'s parsing of `+1 week` and such. Sadly, this essential function is very poorly documented. I wonder whether it would be worth opening this question to more tags that just PHP? Jon Skeet might be able to add a thing or two, he [has been dealing with Date/Time libraries in the past](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/01/the-joys-of-date-time-arithmetic.aspx). In fact, I think I'll ping him.

Comment: @Pekka IIRC PHP used gnutime() once for that, but Derick has since re-written the code.

Comment: @Pekka In this exact case I'm comparing "+1 Month" and MySQL's DATE_ADD(timestamp, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), they differ.

Comment: @preinheimer. So what method of calculating intervals do you think you'll go with? We've seen about 3 of them here.

Comment: [This is a standard case of standards](http://xkcd.com/927/).

Comment: In the end, since there is no standard, you wind up picking a methodology that you think most people will expect, and you document it so they'll know what to expect. Nothing more can be done.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the POSIX.1-2001 standard, next month (as in incrementing `tm_mon` before calling `mktime`) is done by adjusting the values until they fit. So, for example, next month from January 31, 2001 is March 3, 2001. This is because the `tm_mday` of 31 isn't valid with `tm_mon` of 1 (February), so it is normalized to `tm_mon` of 2 (March) and `tm_mday` of 3.

The next month from January 31, 2000 is March 2, 2000, because Feb. has 29 days that year. The next month from January, 1 2038 doesn't exist, depending.

[The great thing about standards is there are so many to chose from](http://xkcd.com/927/). Check the SQL standard, I bet you can find a different meaning of next month. I suspect ISO 8601 may give you yet another choice. Point is, there are many different behaviors, the meaning of 'next month' is very domain-specific.

edit: I *think* I've found how SQL-92 handles it, apparently asking for next month from January 31 is an error.

Links:

- SQL-92: http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt
- POSIX: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ (though apparently that version now defers to ISO C, which doesn't seem as clear. The mktime manpage on my machine is clear, though)
- ISO C: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf
- Java: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: +1 Interesting. I think the point of this question is not so much to find *one* standard but to find out which ones are likely used, and which library adheres to which one. Do you know any documentation that defines the behaviour of `POSIX.1-2001`?

Comment: @derobert, Good answer. Do you have a link? There are about as many standards as there are answers from people on the street. No widely accepted standard for sure, and the answers from this POSIX standard are such as no human would expect.

Comment: @JonathanM: Added some links.

Comment: @derobert, i hope you don't mind the link I added. Feel free to roll it back if you do.

Comment: Thanks, it would appear (even after a bounty) that the problem isn't formally defined outside particular spaces that documented their own solutions. Thanks for collecting a few answers, and for everyone who submitted additions to the list of links.

Comment: @preinheimer. Good question. Good discussion. Thanks. What do you think you'll do?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the defacto standard is ISO 8601. Unfortunately, there are many ambiguities, for example:

Date arithmetic is not defined

```
2001-03-30 + P1M = 2001-04-29 (Add 30 days)
2001-03-30 + P1M = 2001-04-30 (Add 1 mon.)
```

Addition is not commutative or associative

```
2001-03-30 + P1D + P1M = 2001-04-30
2001-03-30 + P1M + P1D = 2001-05-01
```

Subtraction is not the inverse of Addition.

Precision of decimal fractions can vary.

The full specification can be found at http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=26780

I think each product is attempting to adhere to an impossible to implement standard. The ambiguous parts are open to interpretation and so everyone interprets. This is the same standard that opened us up to the Y2K bug!!

Myself, I favor an implementation that converts a date/time to a 1970 based number (UNIX timestamp), performs the calculation and converts back. I believe this is the approach taken by Oracle/MySQL. I am surprised that more attention has not been paid this issue, as it is really important, sometimes critical, in so many applications. Thanks for the question!

Edit: While doing some more reading, I found Joe Celko's thoughts on different date/time representations and standardization [HERE](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporal-datatypes-in-sql-server/).

Comment: Another(Markus Kuhn's) view on ISO 8601 standards here().  RFC 3339 and RFC 2822, both referenced on http://www.twinsun.com/tz/tz-link.htm may also be relevant.  I think the main issue is that you are concerned with months, rather than days or years.  Days and years are astronomically defined, while months are an artificial construct depending whose calendar you intend to follow.

Comment: The first URL linked in this comment notes :  "Both day and year are useful units of structuring time, because the position of the sun on the sky, which influences our lives, is described by them. However the 12 months of a year are of some obscure mystic origin and have no real purpose today except that people are used to having them (they do not even describe the current position of the moon). "

Answer (score 1):

Query:

```
SELECT
ADDDATE(DATE('2010-12-31'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 'Dec + Month',
ADDDATE(DATE('2011-01-31'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 'Jan + Month',
ADDDATE(DATE('2011-02-28'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 'Feb + Month',
ADDDATE(DATE('2011-03-31'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 'Mar + Month';
```

Output:

```
    Dec + Month  Jan + Month  Feb + Month   Mar + Month
    2011-01-31   2011-02-28   2011-03-28    2011-04-30
```

My conclusion:

1. Calculate the number of days in the month of the input date.
2. Add that many days to the input date.
3. Check if the day in the resulting date exceeds the maximun number of days in the resulting month.
4. If yes, then change the resulting day to maximum day of the resulting month.

> If you add MONTH, YEAR_MONTH, or YEAR and the resulting date has a day that is larger than the maximum day for the new month, the day is adjusted to the maximum days in the new month

[source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Problem here is that it doesn't mention that the month is actually the month from the input date.

Comment: +1 cool, I wasn't aware that the mySQL  manual explains its date logic in this depth.

Answer (score 1):

[Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) in Java chooses the previous valid date when an invalid one is created. For example, `2011-01-31 + P1M = 2011-02-28`. I believe this is the most widely chosen default choice in date-time libraries, and thus a de facto standard.

[ThreeTen/JSR-310](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten) provides a strategy pattern for this, with four choices, see the [code](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten/blob/master/src/main/java/javax/time/calendar/DateResolvers.java).

More amusing is the question of what the answer to `2011-01-31 + P1M-1D` is. If you add the month, then resolve the invalid date, then subtract the day, you get 2011-02-27. But I think most users expect 2011-02-28 because the period is being added in a single lump. See how ThreeTen handles this [here](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten/blob/f94f8c346dac455cc5a3238bee39504fa7bdd5b6/src/main/java/javax/time/calendar/LocalDate.java#L648).

I have considered trying to write a general purpose best practices in date/time calculations, or actual spec, but haven't really had the time!

Comment: Update: JSR 310 has been implemented as the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

First day of the month + 1 month should equal the first of the next month. Trying this on SQL Server

```
          SELECT CAST ('01/01/2012' AS DateTime), DATEADD (m, 1, '01/01/2012')
UNION ALL SELECT CAST ('02/01/2012' AS DateTime), DATEADD (m, 1, '02/01/2012')
UNION ALL SELECT CAST ('03/01/2012' AS DateTime), DATEADD (m, 1, '03/01/2012')
UNION ALL SELECT CAST ('04/01/2012' AS DateTime), DATEADD (m, 1, '04/01/2012')
UNION ALL SELECT CAST ('05/01/2012' AS DateTime), DATEADD (m, 1, '05/01/2012')
```

This results in

```
----------------------- -----------------------
2012-01-01              2012-02-01             
2012-02-01              2012-03-01             
2012-03-01              2012-04-01             
2012-04-01              2012-05-01             
2012-05-01              2012-06-01
```

Last day of this month + 1 month should equal last day of next month. This should go for next month, current month, 10 months down, etc.

```
          SELECT CAST ('01/31/2012' AS DateTime), DATEADD (m, 1, '01/31/2012')
UNION ALL SELECT CAST ('01/30/2012' AS DateTime), DATEADD (m, 1, '01/30/2012')
UNION ALL SELECT CAST ('01/29/2012' AS DateTime), DATEADD (m, 1, '01/29/2012')
UNION ALL SELECT CAST ('01/28/2012' AS DateTime), DATEADD (m, 1, '01/28/2012')
UNION ALL SELECT CAST ('01/27/2012' AS DateTime), DATEADD (m, 1, '01/27/2012')
UNION ALL SELECT CAST ('01/26/2012' AS DateTime), DATEADD (m, 1, '01/26/2012')
```

This results in

```
----------------------- -----------------------
2012-01-31              2012-02-29             
2012-01-30              2012-02-29             
2012-01-29              2012-02-29             
2012-01-28              2012-02-28             
2012-01-27              2012-02-27             
2012-01-26              2012-02-26
```

See how 31, 30, 29 all become feb 29 (2012 is a leap year).

p.s. I took off the time parts (all zeroes) to help make it more readable

Comment: I'm really looking for a standards based answer on this, rather than a pool of opinions.

Comment: @preinheimer, It *has* to be a pool of opinions, because if you ask the question to folks out on the street, you're going to get varying answers. They're not bound by any standard out there. And since date software must model real life interpretations of units of time, the software must either clarify expectations or clearly define how *it* will interpret such phrases.

Comment: What about 2nd-to-last day of this month? What's next month from January 29th, 2001? Is "next month" symmetrical with "last month"?

Comment: Presumably, with multiple standards bodies existing to codify prevailing and logically correct opinions into standards. One of them has done so.

Comment: I downvoted because I think this is a very interesting question and while I agree with this opinion, it's just an opinion and not a defined set of rules to base one's work on, which is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer; I have flagged it as such.

Answer (score 0):

There is no widely accepted standard. The reason for the different implementations is that folks can't agree on what the standard should be. Many popular software systems give answers that no one would expect. Documentation is always necessary, therefore, to tell the user what your system will deliver. You choose a methodology, however, based on what you think *most* folks will expect.

I think most people on the street would agree that:

1. You can't define a 'month' by a certain number of days. So...
2. When it's Jan 31 and someone says "I'll meet you a month from today", they mean the last day of February. Basically, it's add to the month, then find the day number that is closest to today without exceeding it.

The exception comes in accounting, where sometimes a month means 30 days.

EDIT: I asked some folks around here, "If it's March 31 and someone says I'll meet you a month from today, what day are you going to meet them?" Most said, April 30, but a few said April 28 because it's four weeks away. The few were interpreting work schedules and thinking "if we met on this weekday, we'll meet again on the same weekday". Basically, if they met on the last Thursday of the month, and they're due to meet in one month, it'll be on the last Thursday of *that* month.

So, there ya go. :\

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment? Help me improve my answer to remove your downvote.

Comment: Well, it's not really an answer to the question, is it? The OP is asking for defined standards to base his work on. The way I understand him, it doesn't mean the standard has to be generally accepted, just that there is *some* set of defined rules to work with. Are you claiming no such sets of rules exist? I think that's highly unlikely.

Comment: @Pekka, yes. That's what I'm claiming. I mentioned in the first sentence why they don't. Now, there may be a little-used, little-recognized standard tucked away in ISO somewhere, but that's not really a standard. It's of no use.

Comment: that's exactly what I'm having a hard time believing - so many things in our civilization depend on date calculation, there *must* exist defined rulesets for how to deal with this. An ISO standard would be a good answer to this question IMO, no matter how little used... If it really turns out there are none, I'll gladly upvote your answer but I'm not convinced yet.

Comment: @Pekka, Since there's no way to prove a standard doesn't exist (you can't prove a negative), you really should remove the downvote until you prove a useable, widely-accepted standard does exist. At that point, I will be glad to downvote myself. :)

Comment: @Jonathan M, the question wasn't about a "usable, widely-accepted standard", it was a question about whether there was any standard at all. As such, your answer...well...isn't one.

Comment: @zzzzBov, I think you're underestimating the OP's interest in usability. Software is always about usability. To downvote on the assumption that usability is not a concern is error.

Comment: @Jonathan M, I'm not going to **assume** anything about the OP's interest in usability. If there *is* an interest in usability the onus is on the OP to express his dissatisfaction with the standards provided, and explicitly request a standard that is more accessible. Answer the question being asked.

Comment: @Jonathan the OP is not saying he needs this to interface with end-users - it could be that he's writing an API. End-user usability is an entirely different issue

Comment: @Pekka, programmers are users, too. In absence of a standard, they have to either have documentation telling them what to expect, or the software must correctly anticipate what they expect and give it to them. This is the behavior required when there is no standard.

Comment: +1 for no accepted standard - I find it sad that PHP and MySQL appear to use different "standards" for date arithmetic (pointed out in other answers). Many applications combine PHP and MySQL which means obtaining consistent results throughout an application unlikely with respect to date manipulation. Now for another lively debate, lets look for "standards" with respect to rounding financial calculations.

Comment: @NealB: "Let's look at 'standards' with respect to rounding financial calculations." ... Trouble-maker. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the mysql date function :

SELECT ADDDATE('2011-01-31', INTERVAL 1 MONTH) // 2011-02-28

Input date with leap year

SELECT ADDDATE('2012-01-31', INTERVAL 1 MONTH) // 2012-02-29

Answer (score 0):

In the .NET framework the behavior of [System.DateTime.AddMonths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx?) is as follows:

> The AddMonths method calculates the resulting month and year, taking
>   into account leap years and the number of days in a month, then
>   adjusts the day part of the resulting DateTime object. If the
>   resulting day is not a valid day in the resulting month, the last
>   valid day of the resulting month is used. For example, March 31st + 1
>   month = April 30th [rather than April 31st].

I've tested how it works exactly:

```
Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(2008,2,27).AddMonths(1));
Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(2008,2,28).AddMonths(1));
Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(2008,2,29).AddMonths(1));
Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(2011,2,27).AddMonths(1));
Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(2011,2,28).AddMonths(1));
Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(2008,1,30).AddMonths(1));
Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(2008,1,31).AddMonths(1));
Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(2011,1,30).AddMonths(1));
Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(2011,1,31).AddMonths(1));
/* output
3/27/2008 12:00:00 AM
3/28/2008 12:00:00 AM
3/29/2008 12:00:00 AM
3/27/2011 12:00:00 AM
3/28/2011 12:00:00 AM
2/29/2008 12:00:00 AM
2/29/2008 12:00:00 AM
2/28/2011 12:00:00 AM
2/28/2011 12:00:00 AM
    */
```