# Is there a recommendation or norm on how to add months to a date when there is carry?

Tags: date, intervals

ISO-8601 defines time intervals, for example `P1M` is one month.

However it seems that is does not mandate how to determine what day is one month from a given date.

I looked up the documentation of [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) and in their implementation, given YYYY-MM-DD, adding one month is adding 1 to MM, and then normalizing (if MM is greater than 12, then increment years, then if DD is greater than the number of days of the resulting month, then carry to next month).

However this can produce inconsistencies:

- 2020-01-29 + P1M = 2020-02-29
- 2020-01-30 + P1M = 2020-03-01
- 2020-01-31 + P1M = 2020-03-02
- 2020-02-01 + P1M = 2020-03-01 ‽, note that this this is sooner than previously

Moreover, with this method, if I specify an interval of one month and one day, should I first add one month, then one day, or should I add first one day, then one month?

- 2020-01-30 + P3D + P1M = 2020-02-02 + P1M = 2020-03-02
- 2020-01-30 + P1M + P3D = 2020-03-01 + P3D = 2020-03-04, so later if we add months first

The question is: is there anywhere a canonical way to proceed when adding an interval to a date, when the interval specifies years or months, which are variable durations?

Comment: [This previous posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614361/standards-for-date-time-addition) might be of interest. I am not aware of any improvement since then.

Comment: @petern0691 This is indeed interesting, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual implementation of the term month in interval form is left mostly unspecified in most, if not all, standards on purpose.

The loosely accepted definition is about 30 days. The integer rounding of 365.25 / 12.

The method used varies on several factors:

Simplicity and Convenience:

It is easier to remember common days.

- My electric bill is due on the 11th of every month. This is problematic when day is greater than 28.
- I get paid the last day of the month.
- The meeting is on the second Tuesday of each month.

Ease of calculation:

Fixed Month definition.

- 30 day grace period for new purchases.

Astronomical:

Lunar Based:
My apologies for the poorly condensed descriptions.

- Synodic: Based on phases of the Moon: 29.18 to about 29.93 days(formed the basis of our modern system)
- Sidereal: Based on "fixed" star passing. 27.321 days
- Tropical: Based on celestial bodies at the Spring(northern hemisphere) Equinox: 27.321 days
- Anomalistic: based on angle off of the elliptic orbit: 27.554 days
- Draconic: based on angle off of the elliptic plane: 27.212 days

An even solar month would be:

About 365.2422 / 12 ~= 30.43685 days

An even calendar month would be:

Non-leap years: 30.4166666667 days

Leap years: 30.5 days

Or in terms of Weeks:
Just over 4 Weeks.

This is not meant to be an exhaustive list. There are many more historic or esoteric definitions not included here.

If I have missed one in use today, please let me know.

---

The main take away is that no single definition fits all purposes.

Be consistent and transparent:

Pick one and stick with it.
Let everyone know.